# IOS TabBar preload all tabs

Tags: ios, json, cocoa, uitabbarcontroller, preloader

I've a tabbar based app. And on each VC (tab) I have a JSON service call. What's the best way to preload all the views on the tabs, so when users tap on the tab, it is already loaded? Is there any method to make a view load?

Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to follow the MVC design pattern and make the service calls independent of the UI. When you app launches start loading all (using a singleton class or an instance of your "`ServiceCommunicator`" class in the `AppDelegate`). Then when clicking on a particular tab and an UIViewController is loaded it would check up with your "`ServiceCommunicator`" class and if it's still loading it data it will show some loading message otherwise it will display the downloaded data...

Comment: seems legit. Well it was my first app. With 2 months of learning, and coming from Front-End, so, I know that I've made some things bad. Specially because I had no notions about MVC ou OOC. But in my next app, surely I will make things a little bit more right!

Tks for the help man!